# Disable Download flash file popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, iframe

I'm building a website and one of my pages has an iframe which contains a flash file.

I'm including this iframe like this :

```
<iframe src="http://test.com/aflashanimation.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So in `aflashanimation.html` there's a swf object.

But when I the website I'm building with Firefox or IE, a popup appears telling me to download the swf file.

I don't know how to get rid of that popup.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the sandbox tag and select which restrictions you want to set on that iframe.

More documentation on w3school: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp